# Regex php inside array

Tags: php, regex

I don't know how to work with regex.
I get from file_get_contents (So is a string):

`"sources": [{"file":"https:\/\/www40.playercdn.net\/98\/0\/Ya2t561cTjn95vvqwekm7w\/1475599977\/161003\/839RHzKW43tP1DAt.mp4","label":"360p","default":"true"},{"file":"https:\/\/www61.playercdn.net\/100\/1\/sRVvFxxRF2pk26D8D7C_1A\/1475599977\/161003\/950LRfeY1xeAfNQ3.mp4","label":"720p"}] ,"logo": {`

And I need to extract only

`https:\/\/www40.playercdn.net\/98\/0\/Ya2t561cTjn95vvqwekm7w\/1475599977\/161003\/839RHzKW43tP1DAt.mp4`

and

`https:\/\/www61.playercdn.net\/100\/1\/sRVvFxxRF2pk26D8D7C_1A\/1475599977\/161003\/950LRfeY1xeAfNQ3.mp4`

And need to know that first URL is 360p and second 720p

Thank you

Comment: Could you post somewhere all your file (in a service like ideone or other).

Answer (score 1):

I would not use regex for this. Instead use `json_decode` to convert the data to an array. Json is basically string-based objects that can be easily transmitted over the internet.

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

You can now use normal php array notation to get the values you want.

Comment: Sorry i dont explain that this is a string. I get all the website code because use file_get_content and now need only that 2 lines.

Comment: @AntônioCorreia your string is in a format called json, that you can decode into an array using `json_decode($string, true)`. You can read more about json here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: @Thomas but is possible to use json_decode in a file_Get_content? that this is on a javascript?

Comment: @AntônioCorreia you can just call `json_decode` after you get the content.